# Calling the fuction GetEthToTokenInputPrice

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, addresses, uniswap

Please help since I'm getting furious over this problem.
I deployed a contract to the ropsten network, and am trying to call a function getEthToTokenInputPrice to see if it worked through solidity. I have no idea how this works.

This is what i currently have

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract A { // This doesn't have to match the real contract name. Call it what you like.
   address addressB;
   function setAddresssB(address _addressB) public{ // No implementation, just the function signature. This is just so Solidity can work out how to call it.
       addressB = _addressB;
   }
}

contract B {
  function getEthToTokenInputPrice(uint256 eth_sold) external view returns (uint256 tokens_bought) ;
  }
```